# too many resources requesred error on Jetson Nano with Tensorflow simple matrix determinant

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia-jetson-nano

hope I’m in the right place to post this.

I re-installed from scratch my Jetson with the latest JetPack 4.5 and Tensorflow 2.3.

The simple Tensorflow sample code (MNIST) works OK.

When I try to run :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

D = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [-3., -7., -1.], [0., 5., -2.]]))
print("Shape of D: ", D.shape)

print(tf.linalg.det(D))
```

I get the following error :

```
F tensorflow/core/kernels/determinant_op_gpu.cu.cc:136] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel( DeterminantFromPivotedLUKernel<Scalar, false>, config.block_count, config.thread_per_block, 0, device.stream(), config.virtual_thread_count, n, lu_factor.data(), pivots, nullptr, output.data()) status: Internal: too many resources requested for launch
```

Can anybody tell me if I’m doing something wrong or if this is some bug for which I should find a workaround ?

Comment: Did you tried with Tensorflow 2.4?

Comment: No, not yet available for JetPack 4.5